# EFCore injecting services in DbCommandInterceptor

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

As I can see from the database interceptors I found for EF Core, they must be registered in `Startup.cs` using the `AddInterceptors` method. This method receives an instance, making the interceptor a singleton.

I need to inject a scoped service in the interceptor and this way it's not possible.

Is there any way to add scoped db interceptors to a `DbContext`?

```
services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString(...)
    .AddInterceptors(new DatabaseLogIntgerceptor());
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> This method receives an instance, making the interceptor a singleton.

Actually it isn't singleton, but scoped.

`AddDbContext` has [several overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontext?view=efcore-3.1), all having 2 optional arguments

> **contextLifetime**
> The lifetime with which to register the `DbContext` service in the container.
>
> **optionsLifetime**
> The lifetime with which to register the `DbContextOptions` service in the container.

both defaulting to `ServiceLifetime.Scoped`. `optionsLifetime` also controls the scope of calling the options configuration action.

So by default

```
.AddInterceptors(new DatabaseLogIntgerceptor())
```

will be called per each scope, thus making possible to inject scoped service in it.

As of how to do that, you have to use the `AddDbContext` overloads with action receiving `IServiceProvider` and resolve the services (or the inteceptor) from it, for instance

```
services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>((sp, options) => options
    .UseSqlServer(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString(...)
    )
    .AddInterceptors(
        sp.GetRequiredService<DatabaseLogInterceptor>()
    )
);
```